# "cannot refer to unexported name" при вызове функции из пакета

Tags: golang

Есть главный файл:

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "./extensions"
)

func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    s := http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files/"))) 
    router.HandleFunc("/", handlers.Index)
    router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(s)
    http.Handle("/", router) 

    handlers.sayYess()        
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil) 
}
```

И файл *handlers.go*:

```
package handlers

import (
  "log"
)

func sayYess() {
    log.Println("yess")
}
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "hello")
}
```

Функция `sayYess()` не вызывается - пишет:

> cannot refer to unexported name handlers.makeCache

и

> undefined: handlers.makeCache

Почему другие функции пакета работают, а эта - нет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разобрался. Как ни странно, первая буква должна быть большой:

```
func SayYess() {
    log.Println("yess")
}
```

Comment: Это не странность. Это способ объявления функций, переменных и т.п. публичными или приватными: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: Кстати раз самостоятельно получилось разобраться - отметьте своё решение как ответ.